NoSuchMethodError no static or non-static method
I'm trying to integration RN to existing android app via following official docs
app is successfully installed and working on device but working only native codes
app has been crashed when app trying to render RN view with below error message
Pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Lcom/facebook/react/devsupport/CxxInspectorPackagerConnection$WebSocketDelegate

at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportSoLoader.staticInit

error is occurred calling something about init RN ex) ReactRootView.startReactApplication
I assume that something wring with setup by multiple android modules
re-build and check again official docs few times
